# What does uintptr_t have to do with strict aliasing?

Tags: c, strict-aliasing, dpdk

I was doing some research on strict aliasing and how to handle it and found [this commit](https://github.com/DPDK/dpdk/commit/76746eb13f088856711b2787ea5a0c5c29e46dbf) on DPDK.

To fix strict aliasing (according to the comments), they are casting the `void*` parameters `src` and `dst` into `uintptr_t`. And then using the casted versions.

In my understanding, this should do nothing with the strict aliasing rule since there is no mention of casting to `uintptr_t` in the rule itself.

Would a cast to `uintptr_t` really help strict-aliasing? Or would this just fix some possible warnings from GCC?

Comment: That commit just looks like bogus to me, the compiler is not allowed to assume that void * arguments do not alias anyways afaik, I don't think const changes anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would a cast to uintptr_t really help strict-aliasing?

No, it would not.

> Or would this just fix some possible warnings from GCC?

"Fix" in the sense of disguising the strict-aliasing violations well enough that the compiler does not diagnose them, yes, it might. And presumably it indeed did so for whoever made that change.

This is pernicious, because now, not only may the compiler do something unwanted with the code, but you cannot even prevent it from doing so by passing it the `-fno-strict-aliasing` option (or whatever similar option a different compiler might provide).  Worse, it might work fine with the compiler used today, but break months or years later when you upgrade to a new version or when you switch to a different C implementation.

Comment: The Standard deliberately avoids requiring that all implementations be suitable for low-level programming.  Thus, compiler writers who are making a bona fide effort to make implementations be suitable for such purposes will need to use their own judgment rather than the Standard to balance optimizations with low-support level semantics.  Things like integer-to-pointer casts often appear in code that requires low-level semantics that would be broken by attempts at "optimization", seldom appear otherwise, and should thus work with any compilers that seek to support low-level programming.

Comment: I do not disagree, @supercat.  Certainly C does not require compilers to perform any particular category of optimization or to use any particular information to guide whatever optimizations they do perform.  But whether there is a strict-aliasing violation is a function of the code, not of the compiler. Inserting conversions to integer and back does not change whether accessing a particular object via a pointer to a particular data type constitutes a strict-aliasing violation, regardless of whether there is any *bona fide* reason to expect that it will work as intended anyway.

Comment: The whole purpose of the Strict Aliasing rule is to specify when compilers must accommodate the possibility that even straightforward-looking code might actually be doing something "tricky".  It was never intended to invite compilers to ignore the possibility that that tricky-looking code might do tricky things.  There's no definition of "tricky looking", but the more generally-tricky things code does, the more unlikely it would be that a quality compiler will miss all of them.

Comment: @supercat, I was not involved in drafting any part of the standard, but the intent of the strict aliasing rule has always seemed to me to be *exactly* that compilers are permitted to assume that programs do not attempt to perform certain kinds of tricky things.  Compilers don't need the SAR to instruct them that they need to accommodate things that programs are permitted to do regardless of the SAR.

Comment: The SAR was merely intended to allow customers to perform optimizations *which their particular customers would find useful* without having to accommodate corner cases *which wouldn't matter to their customers*.  Because different customers have different needs, the Committee expected that compiler writers would be better placed than the Committee to recognize which corner cases would matter to their particular customers.  In general, the decision of whether some action X should be defined or not was made not based upon the question "Would most programmers find X useful", but rather...

Comment: ..."Are there any situations where mandating X might make the language less useful?"  If a feature or guarantee could be cheaply and usefully supported on most implementations, the only compiler writers who would be expected to care about whether the Standard mandates support for it would be those targeting platforms or purposes for which the cost of such support would exceed the value.  If no such implementations would exist, the question of whether the Standard mandates support should be moot and thus not worth addressing.

Comment: There is a widespread myth that the phrase "non-portable or erroneous" excludes the possibility of "not portable to implementations where the cost of supporting a particular feature or guarantee would exceed the value, or whose authors would claim that it does, but correct on all others".  The published Rationale, however, makes very clear that the definition of "conforming program" was drawn broadly to avoid demeaning useful programs that are non-portable but are correct when run on implementations that support the necessary features and guarantees.

Comment: For the most part, @supercat, I still don't disagree, except about your earlier claim regarding the purpose of the Strict Aliasing rule.  In particular, your followup comments seem more consistent with the intent I describe, that the SAR frees compilers to make certain assumptions (if they so choose), than with the one you asserted, that the SAR obligates compilers to avoid making certain other assumptions.  I'm pretty sure I did not say that programs that violate the SAR must fail, but I also don't see a plausible reading of the standard that makes such programs conforming.

Comment: Moreover, in the case of the SAR, there is no need to rely on the "non-portable or erroneous" language in the definition of UB.  Paragraph 4/2 specifies that "If a 'shall' or 'shall not' requirement that appears outside of a constraint or runtime- constraint is violated, the behavior is undefined."  That applies to violations of the SAR.  What compilers should do under the circumstances is explicitly not directed by the standard, so I wholly agree that it is to be expected and was presumably the intent that that would be driven by compiler customers.

Comment: The language you describe means that while most standards use the terms "shall" and "shall not" for constraints whose violation would render something non-conforming, the C Standard rather unusually employs them for constraints whose violation would prevent a program from being *strictly* conforming, and would sometimes require that an implementation issue a diagnostic, but would otherwise merely place a program's behavior *outside the jurisdiction of the Standard* without making it non-conforming.

Comment: According to the Standard, if there exists somewhere in the universe a conforming C implementation that will accept some particular source text and process it usefully, that source text is a "conforming C program", regardless of whether the Standard would impose any requirements upon how any implementations process it.  Note that in describing UB, the Standard says "There is no difference in emphasis among these three ", with the "first" referring to violations of constraints.  A program that violates constaints is thus no less conforming than one whose behavior the Standard neglects...

Comment: ...to describe, but which some implementations describe anyway.

Comment: You are right, @supercat, I confused the requirements for "conforming" with those for "strictly conforming".  The standard does not require conforming implementations to reject programs that violate the SAR or otherwise exhibit undefined behavior, therefore such programs can conform (but not strictly conform).  And as far as the standard is concerned the combination of such a program with an implementation that accepts it can, in principle, produce any behavior.  Among the plausible behaviors are some that you characterize as suitable for low-level programming and some that you ...

Comment: ... characterize as unsuitable for such programming.  Again, we agree on this, or at least I think we do.  Still the only matter on which I think we disagree is the intent of the SAR.

Comment: The general purpose of the SAR is to avoid requiring that compilers refrain from making certain optimizations in cases where they would be useful.  With the exception of the scenario where an object is accessed using its actual type, the explicitly-allowed scenarios are all ones which--in the absence of mandated support--well-meaning compiler writers might not accommodate in all cases.  In the absence of the Standard's mandate, I'd regard it as far more reasonable for a compiler to optimize `void test(int *p, char *q) { *p+=1; *q+=1; *p+=1; }` by consolidating the accesses to `*p` than...

Comment: ...for a compiler to optimize `void test(int *p, int *q) { *p += 1; *(unsigned short*)q += 1; *p +=1;}` to do likewise, and I doubt I'd be alone in that opinion.  Thus, if for some reason one wanted compilers to support both the constructs, it would be much more important to mandate support for the first than the second.

Answer (score 0):

The "strict aliasing rules" specify situations where *even implementations that are not intended to be suitable for low-level programming* must allow for the possibility of aliasing between seemingly-unrelated objects.  Compilers which are designed to be suitable for low-level programming are allowed to, and will, extend the language by behaving meaningfully--typically processing constructs "in a documented fashion characteristic of the environment" in more circumstances than mandated by the Standard, especially in the presence of constructs that would generally be useless otherwise.

Relatively few programs that aren't intending to access storage in low-level fashion will perform integer-to-pointer conversions.  Thus, implementations that treat such conversions as an indication that they should avoid making any assumptions about the pointers formed thereby will be able to usefully process a wider range of programs than those which don't, without having to give up many opportunities for genuinely-useful optimizations.  While it would be better to have the Standard specify a syntax for the purpose of erasing any evidence of pointer provenance, conversions through integer types presently work for almost all compilers other than clang.